# ASP.NET Request.Url is repeating the URL 3 times

Tags: asp.net, url, request, httphandler

I have a HttpHandler that is called whenever an image extension is accessed. This is what I have in the HttpHandler as a simple test:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{       
    context.Response.Write(context.Request.Url.ToString());
    context.Response.End();
}
```

According to Firebug, the first time the page is refreshed (Ctrl+F5), the URL is shown correctly in the response. However, if I refresh it again (F5), it'll repeat the URL 3 times:

First time:

> http://server/image.jpg

Subsequent times:

> http://server/image.jpghttp://server/image.jpghttp://server/image.jpg

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I have a similar problem with a normal webform's Page_load called twice if there's an Image control that has an empty ImageUrl.

For your case, I'm very puzzled as well, have you performed a debug and step-through?

Comment: I can't remember how I fixed the problem, but it was completely unrelated to writing the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and refresh page in different browsers and there is no repeating URL.

Comment: Turns out I set the wrong ContentType (it was setting it as `image.png?width=250`). Dunno why this would produce 3 times the request URL on a refresh though.